# Taking user input then making a calculation from a button press (HTML/JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html

I just started learning code a few days ago and have been trying to build a basic web design from scratch using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

What I want to happen is have a box that you put your height in inches in, then click a button to calculate, then it displays your height divided by 7. My problem is that the calculate button displays nothing. Here's my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPEhtml>
<html lang="en-US">
<!--A banana is about 7 inches -->
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
    <title> Banana For Scale </title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="question">
        <h1> How many bananas tall are you? </h1>
    </div>
    <div class=number-input>
        <p>Enter your height in inches. </p>
        <input type="number" id='myNumber'>
    </div>
    <div class='button'>
        <button onclick="myCalculation()">Calculate</button>
    </div>
    <div class='answer'>
        <p id='display'></p>
        <img class='banana' src="https://pajamasmed.hs.llnwd.net/e1/trending/user-
    content/51/files/2017/03/bananas-03.jpg" alt='banana'>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my code located in script.js:

```
var bananaHeight() = document.getElementById("myNumber" / 7);

function myCalculation() {
    document.getElementById("display") = bananaHeight();
}
```

Comment: Why did you choose to put the `/7` there? Why do you believe that `var bananaHeight() = ...` is correct?

Comment: I'm sure you could figure this out yourself using the debugging tools in the browser or by reading up on some basic tutorials.

Comment: Unless your element's id is `NaN`, then I suggest making `"myNumber"` into a number and not a string, and moving `/ 7` outside of the `getElementById` function call

Comment: to get the value from an input element you need to document.getElementById('id').value; After you have got the value you can then divide it by 7, document.getElementById('id').value / 7.
Next, you are trying to declarate a variable and at the same time trying to do a function call? var banaHeight()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a solution for you. Check the Comments to understand what i'm dooing there..

> To learn more about JavaScript try [Codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/) - learning by dooing and its free ;)

```js
function myCalculation(){
  var bananaHeight = document.getElementById('myNumber').value / 7;   // Get the Inputvalue and do your calculation (/7)
  document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = bananaHeight;        // display the result of your calculation inside the <p>-Element with the id 'display'
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="question">
    <h1> How many bananas tall are you? </h1>
  </div>
  <div class=number-input>
    <p>Enter your height in inches. </p>
    <input type="number" id='myNumber'>
  </div>
  <div class='button'>
    <button onclick="myCalculation()">Calculate</button>
  </div>
  <div class='answer'>
    <p id='display'></p>
    <img class='banana' src="https://pajamasmed.hs.llnwd.net/e1/trending/user-
content/51/files/2017/03/bananas-03.jpg" alt='banana'>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

There were some syntax errors in your code. Check out the code below..i highly recommend you to check out some basic javascript tutorials.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp

```js
var bananaHeight = function(){ 
return (document.getElementById("myNumber").value/7);
};

function myCalculation() {
document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = bananaHeight();
}
```

```html
<div class="question">
<h1> How many bananas tall are you? </h1>
</div>
<div class=number-input>
<p>Enter your height in inches. </p>
<input type="number" id='myNumber'>
</div>
<div class='button'>
<button onclick="myCalculation()">Calculate</button>
</div>
<div class='answer'>
<p id='display'></p>
<img class='banana' 
src="https://pajamasmed.hs.llnwd.net/e1/trending/user-
content/51/files/2017/03/bananas-03.jpg" alt='banana' >
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your code in my debugger (as suggested by other answers) and the first error is here and prevents your code from loading the script

```
var bananaHeight() = document.getElementById("myNumber" / 7);
```

Next, you try to assign the result of bananaHeight to another function

```
document.getElementById("display")
```

This does not return an editable object. You should use innerHtml, like this

```
document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = bananaHeight;
```

Hope it helps.
Nicolas